# Knockout.js How should I add computed value to observaleArray?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to add to observableArray computed values, my current code is look like this:

```
   self.prices = ko.observableArray();
   .....
   var pax = $("select#ticketsnumber option:selected").val();
        var irt;
        if ($("input[name='isrt']").is(":checked")) {
            irt = 1;
        } else {
            irt = 0;
        }    
    $.each(self.prices(), function (price) {
            price.FinalPrice = ko.computed(function() {
               return prices.Price * irt * parseInt(pax);
        });
    });
```

But I do not have any idea how should I call binding of this computed value (currently this way - `<span name="totalprice" data-bind="text: ko.utils.unwrapObservable($data.FinalPrice)">`) as well as this just seemed like computed value has not been added - binding result show 0.
Data model:

```
  public class PriceItem
        {
            ...
            public string Price { get; set; }
           ...
            public int FinalPrice { get; set; }
        }
```

This is the way how I retrieve data to self.prices:

```
self.getprices = function () {
            var destinationtypefrom = $("select#optionsfrom option:selected").attr("name");
            var destinationtypeto = $("select#optionsto option:selected").attr("name");
            var fromcode = $("select#optionsfrom").val();
            var tocode = $("select#optionsto").val();
            var json = { desttypefrom: destinationtypefrom, desttypeto: destinationtypeto, codefrom: fromcode, codeto: tocode, 'DepartureDate': $("#departure").val(), 'ReturnDate': $("#return").val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetFlights",
                data: json,
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Error == null) {
                        self.prices(result);
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self.prices);
                    } else {
                        $("#modalerror").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
                            var modal = $(this);
                            modal.find("#errormsg").text(result.Error);
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What's `prices.Price`? How does an element inside the `prices` array looks like?

Comment: Price - this is default value returned by web service and added to observableArray from c# class, FinalPrice - this is part of c# class as well, but without value. Value for FinalPrice field I'm adding in Knockout.

Comment: Is `price` a `Number`? `Object`?

Comment: Regarding price. This is derivative of the function, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov, `this` would only refer to `price` if the computed is set as: `ko.computed(function(){...}, price)`.

Comment: @haim770, you have a point. In your answer you seem to have nailed the other way to get a proper reference to the array item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is wrong by assuming the first argument to be the actual element in the `prices` array. In fact, the first argument is the index, the *second* argument is the actual `price` you want to augment.

Also, you seem to have a typo in the `computed` function calculation, it's `price.Price` instead of `prices.Price`.

Try this:

```
$.each(self.prices(), function (index, price) {
    price.FinalPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        return price.Price * irt * parseInt(pax);
    });
});
```

And in your HTML, something like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: prices">
    <span name="totalprice" data-bind="text: FinalPrice"></span>
</div>
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0q1w0u20/)

Comment: This what I got: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj

Comment: This error probably points out that your `self.prices` is not actually an array. Create a Fiddle or show the code that actually gets the data from the server and maps it to `self.prices`.

Comment: I don't think so - without that computed value everything binded properly.

Comment: Create a Fiddle or change my existing Fiddle then.